# Slow transition from UIImagePickerController to another View controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am having an issue where when I open up the app, I land on a "capture photo view", which is a UIImagePickerController with the camera as a source and a custom overlay. When the user swipes from the right edge, it transitions to another view controller. The problem is that the performance when "seguing" is bad. It seems like it takes a second to "stop" the capture session and then it transitions, making it not really fluid.

Any ideas? Thanks guys.

Here is a gif of what's happening:

http://gph.is/1YzYJNv

Comment: Why do you say seguing?  Is a simple push via code is working fine?

Comment: Seguing was the wrong word, I am using the navigationBar to push the next view controller.